# Resize image and crop to new aspect ratio

Tags: php, crop, image-resizing, aspect-ratio

Using this code, uploaded images are being downsized to fit within the set max size, preserving the initial aspect ratio. That works fine.

Now I aim for it to also crop the image, so it changes aspect ratio to 4:3 (horizontal/vertical). Also within a max size of 800px either way.

I have tried various code/ideas I could find on the net, but they seemed to scew the image, only crop or not work at all. How could the aspect cropping be included in the code I already have?

```
$max_width = 800;
$max_height = 800;

$image_size_info = getimagesize($image_temp);
$image_width = $image_size_info[0];
$image_height = $image_size_info[1];

$image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp);

$image_scale = min($max_width/$image_width, $max_height/$image_height);
$new_width = ceil($image_scale * $image_width);
$new_height = ceil($image_scale * $image_height);

$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

imagecopyresampled($canvas, $image_res, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);

imagejpeg($canvas, 'images/image.jpg', 85);

imagedestroy($image_res);
```

PS: Please, the question is about THIS code

Comment: you can try cloudinary http://cloudinary.com/ api, you can post photos and they have a very good scale | aspect and many other good tools

Comment: Thanks, but no thanks. I will stick to this extremely simple and local way. I'm getting closer to the goal now

Comment: yea I understand, I was too Lazy when had the same problem @mowgli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling, this works.

It resizes and crops, so images becomes either 4:3 or 3:4, depending on dominant initial width/height.

When using very small images, there should also be some checking and/or bypassing, so they don't get upscaled etc.

```
$max_width = 800;
$max_height = 800;

$image_size_info = getimagesize($image_temp);
$image_width = $image_size_info[0];
$image_height = $image_size_info[1];

$image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp);

if ($image_height < $image_width) {

    $cropfactor = $image_height / $image_width;
    $cropfactor = ($cropfactor > 0.75) ? $cropfactor : 0.75;
    $max_height = ceil($max_height * $cropfactor);

} elseif ($image_width < $image_height) {

    $cropfactor = $image_width / $image_height;
    $cropfactor = ($cropfactor > 0.75) ? $cropfactor : 0.75;
    $max_width = ceil($max_width * $cropfactor);

}

$new_width = $image_height * $max_width / $max_height;
$new_height = $image_width * $max_height / $max_width;

$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width, $max_height);

if ($new_width > $image_width) {

   $cut_x = 0;
   $cut_y = (($image_height - $new_height) / 2);
   $new_width_canvas = $image_width;
   $new_height_canvas = $new_height;

} else {

   $cut_x = (($image_width - $new_width) / 2);
   $cut_y = 0;
   $new_width_canvas = $new_width;
   $new_height_canvas = $image_height;

}

imagecopyresampled($canvas, $image_res, 0, 0, $cut_x, $cut_y, $max_width, $max_height, $new_width_canvas, $new_height_canvas);

imagejpeg($canvas, 'images/image.jpg', 85);

imagedestroy($image_res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, wether you are running it on shared server or some managed or dedicated server but imagemagick is a really neat tool for all those tasks.

Comment: Yes, I heard about that. But I'm already so close to the goal with what I have, that it seems better to just stick with that. And so this is what my question is about

Comment: Have you tried PHP's (>5.5) imagecrop function yet? http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecrop.php

Comment: No, but that seems to only crop, not resize. And I'm sure I can get imagecopyresampled to perform it fine, with the right calculations. I already crop for a thumbnail too fine. So I just need the right algorithm/calculation for the aspect cropping. Oh, and the server runs php 5.4